# Outlet Partially Not Working

Tags: electrical

I went to change the outlet below my kitchen sink for the dishwasher and garbage disposal. I am I upgrading the original 1993 outlets and switches throughout the house.

- I turned off the breaker and verified no power to the outlet.
- I pulled the outlet from the wall box.
- The connections on the old outlet were:
- Upper Gold - BLACK
- Upper Silver - WHITE
- Lower Gold - RED
- Lower Silver - GROUND
- I wired the new outlet the same way, except I put the ground wire on the ground screw.
- I turned on power and there is no power to outlet!
- With power off, I returned the ground wire to that lower silver screw.
- Now there is power, but the switch for the dishwasher now runs the disposal and the disposal switch still works.
- After more troubleshooting I found that the “so called ground wire” is actually delivering 120v to the outlet.

Time to get my electrician involved, again! Whoever wired this house needs their butts kicked!!

Comment: Sounds like a two-part problem: Ground used as a neutral and tabs removed/not removed. **Upload pictures of the current outlet showing all the wires and of the old outlet**. Particularly interested in whether the tabs on the side are present/removed on the old outlet.

Comment: Ah, the dreaded "cargo cult multi wire branch circuit". - Be of good courage, you can fix this. You will need to look at how the cable is connected at the home service panel, and you may need to engage in a dialog where SE contributors ask you weird questions and you conduct tests to find the answers. The good news is that although your circuit was wired wrong, you seem to have enough wires available and you only need to connect them properly at both ends of the cable.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the box please? That will let us get a decent start on what's going on here.  Also: were any tabs removed from the old outlet, and what's the point of "upgrading" the outlets here? (i.e. is there something specific wrong with them?)

Comment: Are you asking for help in fixing this or is this just a rant? I get that it's rant worthy, but this isn't the place for your rant. If you're calling in an electrician, then we'll just delete this non-question. If you're looking for help in fixing it, please [edit] out the ranty bits (now that you've got it out of your system) and ask a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it stands, it's a rant, not a question.

Comment: I agree with A.I.breveleri. This is a messed up multi wire branch circuit . Measuring black to red should be 240v with the tab broken on the gold screw side. The green should go back to the green screw and the white on the silver side with the tab not broken. In the service panel or breaker box this cable should go to a double breaker ether 1 handle 2 spaces or 2 breakers with a handle tie.  This is called a multi wire branch circuit. The ground should have not been on the silver screw, with a MWBC a single white can be the neutral for both hot circuits as they are on separate legs and why 240